# How to inline a picture in Microsoft PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint

In Microsoft PowerPoint, I am trying to treat a picture as if it were text, in the sense that I want to be a *part of* a text paragraph. (I'm not looking for how to wrap text around a picture.) To explain using HTML terminology, I'm looking for the inline display type. This is possible in Microsoft Word, but I cannot find any way to do it in PowerPoint.

All I seem to be able to do with pictures in PowerPoint is hover them on top of the text and other content.

Unsure whether it's relevant, but in this particular case, I want to fill a number cells of a table with a picture instead of text. I want to be able to resize the columns and have the picture position update accordingly, which doesn't work when just superimposing a picture on top of the cell. I also want to be able to resize the picture itself and have the cell (i.e. its row and column) increase in size accordingly (like if I were to increase the font size).

Comment: Note, I tried to find a more appropriate StackExchange site for this question, but failed to find a good match.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PowerPoint doesn't do inline pictures/shapes.

You *can* fill a table cell with a picture. The problem with that is that as you change the cell proportions, the fill picture stretches to match, which distorts the picture.

If you want to try it, put the cursor in the cell you want to format, rightclick and choose Format Shape.